# Python - Combining two lists of strings to create a matrix/table of their combinations

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

Here is my problem:

```
list1 = ['cake', 'pie', 'bread']
list2 = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
```

I would like to make a matrix/table/dataframe that takes these two lists and creates every permutation of the strings in the list.

```
newTable = 
                 cake       pie        bread     #ColumnHeader
#Index
blue           cake blue    pie blue    bread blue
red            cake red     pie red     bread red
yellow         cake yellow  pie yellow  bread yellow
```

List 1 (which is also the column header) corresponds to the first word in this string pair, while List 2 (the index) is the second word.

I'd like to do this in python, but if matlab is much easier, that is fine. Thanks!

EDIT - Not every permutation, but rather, every permutation where the column header is the first word and the index is the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list1 = ['cake', 'pie', 'bread']
>>> list2 = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow']
>>> list(product(list1, list2))
[('cake', 'blue'), ('cake', 'red'), ('cake', 'yellow'),
 ('pie', 'blue'), ('pie', 'red'), ('pie', 'yellow'),
 ('bread', 'blue'), ('bread', 'red'), ('bread', 'yellow')]
```

If you would like to construct a 2d list that you can index, e.g. `[0][1]`

```
>>> [[(i,j) for i in list1] for j in list2]
[[('cake', 'blue'), ('pie', 'blue'), ('bread', 'blue')],
 [('cake', 'red'), ('pie', 'red'), ('bread', 'red')],
 [('cake', 'yellow'), ('pie', 'yellow'), ('bread', 'yellow')]]
```

Comment: Thanks Cyber. I know about combining two lists like that, but the kicker (at least for me) is making the table where the indices are list 2 and the row headers are list 1.